# How can I run "Command & Conquer: Generals – Zero Hour" on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, command-and-conquer-generals, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I have Windows 7 64-bit, and I'm trying to run *Command & Conquer: Generals – Zero Hour* on it. *Generals* itself works fine, but *Zero Hour* just quits after the splash screen.

I have the latest version (1.04) and made sure I have the latest Nvidia drivers, etc. I have tried all the .INI file tricks and running it in XP compatibility mode, but those don't seem to work.

I've also tried the following:

- Install DirectX 9.0c
- Run as administrator
- Set compatibility to Windows XP SP2/SP3
- Change the `options.ini` for *Zero Hour*; this is in a different folder than the normal *Generals* `options.ini`

Answer (score 7):

The reason that this game no longer works is outlined by the other answer and [this other question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246786/96435).  Basically there was a security hole in Windows 7 and 8 that Microsoft patched that makes certain write protection not work anymore.  There is a simpler and safer solution to the problem than the one outlined in the other answer though (note that there is no workaround for Windows 10).  First, open a command prompt as an administrator:

> Windows button -> cmd.exe -> right-click -> Run as administrator

Run this command (with the exact spaces) to reenable the driver's service:

> sc config secdrv start= demand

You should get a `[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS` message.  Then run this command to start the service:

> sc start secdrv

Then open the game and it should work!  You'll have to start the service every time you want to run this or any other CD-based game with SafeDisc or SecuROM, and you'll probably want to stop it when you're done to reduce security risks.

Comment: This definitely brought me closer to a solution than anything else I've seen before, the game launched but a serious error occurred afterwards. I think this solution ought to work out for most people though, and might just require doing the things others have suggested too.

Comment: worked for me, windows 8.1 64 bit c&c general with daemon tools lite

Answer (score 3):

Some things to try if you haven't already (according to: http://forums.cncnz.com/index.php?showtopic=12319)

- Install DirectX 9.0C
- Run as administrator
- Set compatibility to Windows XP SP3
- Change the options.ini for Zero Hour, this is in a different folder than the normal generals options.ini.

Comment: I've tried all of that already.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that if you have a good machine you could set up a virtual machine with XP and try it from there... it will have a perf hit.. but generals is a little old, so it might be ok..

Comment: I think I'll try the XP compatibility mode next.

Answer (score 2):

Following the instructions on [forums.cncnz.com](http://forums.cncnz.com/topic/12319-how-to-play-generals-zero-hour-in-windows-7-x64/) worked for me. I already had the latest drivers and I installed C&C Generals and Zero Hour. Then (these are I think the most important parts):

1. Try to run C&C. It will not work but it will create this directory: `C:\Users\<your user name>\Documents\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data`.
2. In this directory, create an empty file called `options.ini`.
3. Copy these contents to the file:

> ```
> AntiAliasing = 1
> BuildingOcclusion = yes
> CampaignDifficulty = 0
> DynamicLOD = yes
> ExtraAnimations = yes
> GameSpyIPAddress = 0.0.0.0
> Gamma = 50
> HeatEffects = yes
> IPAddress = 0.0.0.0
> IdealStaticGameLOD = Low
> LanguageFilter = false
> MaxParticleCount = 5000
> MusicVolume = 55
> Resolution = 1366 768
> Retaliation = yes
> SFX3DVolume = 79
> SFXVolume = 71
> ScrollFactor = 60
> SendDelay = no
> ShowSoftWaterEdge = yes
> ShowTrees = yes
> StaticGameLOD = Custom
> TextureReduction = 0
> UseAlternateMouse = yes
> UseCloudMap = yes
> UseDoubleClickAttackMove = no
> UseLightMap = yes
> UseShadowDecals = yes
> UseShadowVolumes = yes
> VoiceVolume = 70
> ```

4. In Windows Explorer, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\EA Games\Command & Conquer Generals Zero Hour`.
5. Right-click on `generals.exe`. Select **Properties**.
6. On the **Compatibility** tab, check **Run this program in compatibility mode for** and in the drop down select **Windows XP (Service Pack 3)**.
7. On the same tab, under **Privilege Level** check the **Run this program as administrator** check box.
8. Press OK and then run the program.

So far this crashed once (with a "serious error" when I changed the settings in game) - apart from that it has worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 7 64-bit as well. Generals did work on my computer at some point but no longer worked for a while. I did try all the fixes you mentioned, and I eventually found out that my problem was caused by a Windows update, specifically, Update KB3086255.  Here's a link to show you how to uninstall the aforementioned update:

Comment: @Texenox What relevant information could he possible have added? how to remove a windows update from your update history?

Comment: @Texenox This question is not "How to uninstall a Windows update", though. They can look that up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try XP mode inside of windows 7

It's a free download from Microsoft

[Download Windows XP mode for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)