# How do I get The Sting (2001) to run on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: pc, windows

So I'm having a hard time trying to run a game named The Sting (2001) on my Windows 7 64 bit laptop. I've tried running it on compatibility mode, but the game just ends up closing right after I hit "play".

I've read that it could be because some of the DLLs required to run the game aren't available anymore on the new Windows versions. I have no idea where to find them, nor do I know how to proceed with that information.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: do you know the exact DLL's you need?

Comment: No, sir. I'm not even sure that's the real issue. It was just a possibility I've seen someone commenting.

Comment: have you tried to check the event viewer? that may bring the exact error which happens when you open the application.

Comment: Actually it doesn't show any error. The game just closes. There's no window popping up with any message.

Comment: I believe it usually happens when the hardware isn't capable of running the game but of course that's not the case here. lol

Comment: i dont mean any popup in the screen itself, but press win+r and type eventvwr.exe and search for the application logs, you can then search an error based on the time you tried to open the application.

Comment: You may want to check [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246786/game-wont-launch-from-cd) in case it's the same issue

Comment: Ooooh I see. I've tried that just now but there's no log event in the times I've tried running the game. D: Or am I looking at the wrong place in the Event Viewer? I did just like you said.

Comment: By the way, I tried the suggested solution in the thread you sent me and I didn't work neither.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is probably stemming from the fact that windows works differently now than it did around the windows 2000/xp era. As such, resources that your game is looking for either don't exist in your current version of windows or are accessed in a completely different manor. My recommendation would be to install a free virtual machine program VM Virtualbox from oracle is a good one.

Hope this helps